# Diffeomorphism $f:U\to V$ then $Df:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^m}$ will be linear isomorphism hence $n=m$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology

${\large let \ U\subset \mathbb{R^n,}V\subset \mathbb{R^m}}$  be open subsets. map $f:{\large U }\to{\large V }$  is called a diffeomorphism if is bijective and both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuously differentiable.

once there is diffeomorphism $f:{\large U }\to{\large V }$
 then $Df:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^m}$ will be ${\large linear \ isomorphism  }$ hence $n=m$. how is this a linear isomorphism??. i know $Df(a)$ is a linear map , but why this is one one and on to ??

Comment: $Df$ is not a map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$. You mean $Df(a)$ for some $a \in U$.

Comment: Please avoid `\large` in titles. (You also use some for no reason in the body of the question but I left them.)

Comment: @OpenBall yes i mean $Df(a)$, for some $a$ in open set $U$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f\circ f^{-1}=Id, f^{-1}\circ f=Id$ implies $Df\circ Df^{-1}=Id, Df^{-1}\circ Df=Id$. It implies $Df$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Why $Df$ is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: What do you get when you apply the chain rule to
$$f \circ f^{-1} = \text{Id}?$$

Answer (score 2):

Given $a \in U$, $f \circ f^{-1} = I_{\mathbb R^m}$, so as $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $f(a)$, $Df(f^{-1}(f(a))) \circ Df^{-1} (f(a)) = I_{\mathbb R^m}$, i.e. $Df(a) \circ Df^{-1} (b) = I_{\mathbb R^m}$, where $b = f(a)$. Similarly, $Df^{-1}(b) \circ Df(a) = I_{\mathbb R^n}$, so $Df(a)$ is invertible and $[Df(a)]^{-1} = Df^{-1}(b)$; it is an isomorphism since it is linear and continuous with a continuous inverse by the assumptions in the question.